# i get an unexpected token error when I do post request with json

Tags: node.js, json, request

I am trying to do a post `request` with json in a format where I use the `option={method, uri, ...}` instead of `request.get(...` because I want to convert this into a function where `method, uri, body` are the parameters

Im calling this request in node.js to a foreign service. Simple `GET` requests to that foreign service worked fine. (By the way I did test if it works via postman)

below is the code where i do the `request`. I have tried without `json:true` and instead of `body`, I tried `json:{"prod...`

```
    request({
      headers: {
        "Content-type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8",
        "Authorization":signature
      },
      method:'POST', 
      uri: PATH+`openapi/apis/api/v1/categorization/predict`,
      json:true,
      body:{"productName": "readymix"} 
    }, (err, res, body) => {
      if(err) console.log(err);
      else console.log(body);
    })
```

I keep getting the following error: `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1` The format looks all correct, I dont know why its not working

=====Problem solved=====

removing `json:true` and fixing `body:{"productName": "readymix"}` to `body:JSON.stringify({"productName": "readymix"})` fixed the problem!

Comment: This is not a valid json: `body:{"productName": "readymix"}`. Do `body:JSON.stringify({"productName": "readymix"})`

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar now it works but Im wondering why I need to stringify JSON. Isnt stringify used to convert javascript object to JSON and parse used to do the other way around?

Comment: Yes right, since you're sending a `json`, you first need to convert object to json!